# Bazel test fails while running "bazel test tensorflow_serving/..."

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to setup TensorFlow Serving using Docker on a Windows machine by following the instructions from https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/docker.html

I have successfully built and run the container and cloned the TensorFlow servings sub-modules. However, while running the command

`"bazel test tensorflow_serving/..."` the error

`Linking of rule: '//tensorflow_serving/batching/test_util:puppet_batch_scheduler_test' failed:gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc ....` is displayed

The complete stack trace is shown in the below image.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve the problem directly, but a workaround could be pulling a docker image where the TF Serving is already compiled such as [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/pldelisle/tensorflow-serving-compiled/).

Comment: On pulling the docker image, an error is displayed stating that the image is not found. "Error: image pldelisle/tensorflow-serving: latest not found"

Comment: Yeah, you might need to specify the version, ie. pldelisle/tensorflow-serving:v1

Comment: I tried giving the version number as you mentioned, however, I still cannot pull the docker image. The error is "Error: image pldelisle/tensorflow-serving:v1 not found"